# How to add a base64 image to tiptap editor?

Tags: image, vue.js, nuxt.js, base64, tiptap

I am using tiptap editor in vue and nuxt js and I wanted the user to upload images but the usual way is to ask them for url from the prompt and then show it or load it. I want an input tag which then calls a function onchange and I get the base64 url, then I want it to load in editor but it doesnt seem to be working.

Here what I did.

```
  data() {
    return {
      editor: new Editor({
        content: '<p>Write Something.....</p>',
        extensions: [
          StarterKit,
          Image.configure({
            allowBase64: true,
            inline: true,
          }),
        ],
      }),
    };
  },
```

The above is my data() part.

```
<label for="img-uploader" id="uploader">Upload</label>
    <input
      id="img-uploader"
      type="file"
      accept="image/jpeg"
      style="display: none"
      @change="addImage"
    />
    addImage(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];

  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const dataURL = e.target.result;
      console.log(dataURL);
      this.editor.chain().focus().setImage({ src: dataURL }).run();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
},
```

Comment: Make sure that addImage method is properly bound to the Vue instance. Ensure that there are no syntax errors in your code